# Solve the System of Equations in $x$ and $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

\begin{equation}
x+\frac{3\,x-y}{x^2+y^2}=3 \tag{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y=\frac{x+3\,y}{x^2+y^2} \tag{2}
\end{equation}

Comment: Solutions are $(x,y)=(1,-1), (2,1),((3-2i)/2,i/2), ((3+2i)/2,-i/2)$, because $4x^4-24x^3+57*x^2-63x+26=(x-1)(x-2)(4x^2-12x+13)$.

Comment: Are you solving over the reals?

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that you are solving this equation over the reals only. This approach is motivated because you have $x^2 + y^2$, and 'anti-symmetric' coefficients.

Set $z = x+iy $.

Take the first equation, add it to $i$ times the second equation, we get

$$ (x+iy) + \frac{ (3-i) ( x-iy) } { x^2 + y^2} = 3.$$

Converting this to $z$, we get

$$ z + \frac{ (3-i) \bar{z} } { |z|^2 } = 3.$$

Recall that $ z \bar{z}  = |z|^2$. Multiplying throughout by $z$, we get

$$ z^2 - 3z + (3-i) = 0.$$

This has solutions $ z= 1-i, z = 2+i.$ This yields $(x,y) = (1,-1), (2,1) $.

---

If you want more problems along the line of using complex substitution, try [Advanced System Of Equations](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/advanced-system-of-equations/?group=pScE5l3AjVaM) and [Making An Equation Complex Doesn't Make It Harder](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/making-an-equation-complex-doesnt-make-it-harder/?group=AtXbc6FcULkP).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Just by inspection, the quartic equation you wrote has two simple solutions $x=1$ and $x=2$. For the other roots, perform the polynomial division.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Inspection... better known as wolfram alpha.

Comment: @Awesome. No ! Just 62 years spent with polynomials ! Wait and see ! Cheers.

Comment: That x=2 looks a bit magical.

Comment: @Awesome. When you see in precalculus high order polynomials, you can bet that there are many simple roots $\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm i$

Comment: also in defense of inspection, by the rational roots test there were only 12 possible rational roots, and since no negative roots are possible here (LHS would be >0) there are only 6 possible rational roots.  1,2,13,26,13/2,13/4.

Comment: @Cluade, I have done the same...but not all Quartic Equations can be solved by Inspection, Thats the reason i asked for alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

We have:

\begin{equation}
x\left(1+\frac{3}{x^2+y^2}\right)=3+\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \tag{3}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y\left(1-\frac{3}{x^2+y^2}\right)=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \tag{4}
\end{equation}

Multiplying Eqn $3$ with $y$ and Eqn $4$ with $x$ we get

\begin{equation}
x\,y\left(1+\frac{3}{x^2+y^2}\right)=3\,y+\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2} \tag{5}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x\,y\left(1-\frac{3}{x^2+y^2}\right)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} \tag{6}
\end{equation} Adding Eqns $5$ and $6$ we get
$$y=\frac{1}{2\,x-3}$$ Using $y=\frac{1}{2\,x-3}$ in Eqn $2$ we get Bi Quadratic in $x$ as:

$$4x^4-24x^3+57x^2-63x+26=0$$

Can i get a Hint without involvement of BiQuadratic...